# Can I evaluate the performance of a company using just OHLC data?

Tags: stocks, calculation, stock-analysis

Is there any way to calculate finance for a company if I have Open, Close, Low, High, Adjusted Value of stocks and it's trade volume in each day, for 6 months?

I read many ways to calculate the finance but it seems my datas are too low.

Do you know any way which can evaluate a company's finances with these data?

Comment: Well, one (pretty weak) way would be to see if it is dipping close to the stock price (or else market cap) that would get it delisted from the stock exchange.  Delisting can have a big impact on company finances, because it'll be harder to sell more stock to raise money.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. The information you are describing is technical data about a stock's **market price** and **trading volume**, only. There is nothing implied in that data about a company's financial fundamentals (earnings/profitability, outstanding shares, market capitalization, dividends, balance sheet assets and liabilities, etc.) All you can infer is positive or negative momentum in the trading of the stock.

If you want to understand if a company is performing well, then you need fundamental data about the company such as you would get from a company's annual and quarterly reports.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to ask in your comment, @HoseynHeydari. You can certainly calculate a number, but probably not a useful one...